# Can we set the speed of the webdriver?

Tags: c#, selenium

Can we set the speed of the webdriver like we use `ISelenium.SetSpeed(String)`. Can we use `IWebdriver.SetSpeed(String)`?

I am writing code in c#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This piece of functionality does not exist anymore. I have to ask what is the reason you would want it though? The reason it no longer exists is because it is not needed anymore, because of extra functionality added such as implicit waiting and having explicit waits via means like fluentwait to make sure that conditions happen before you attempt an action.

If you give more detail on why you need this (perhaps in another question as this question may still be useful for others) I am sure someone will help you.

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks for the info. I was facing an issue. I have been getting an error 'unable to locate element' like I have a registration  form in which once I select a 'State' drop down, the 'City' drop down gets filled with the cities present under that selected 'state'. It takes some time to populate cities once state is selected. I have tried using wait property but still it works sometimes but at times it throws this error. So, I was thinking if i could apply setspeed here.
I have used this: 

driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say it, cause I know it's bad practice.

But I built a test fixture to log and select cases at whim.  These cases are ran through a background worker.  While I have explicit waits for every one of the Selenium Commands I use, I needed to slow it down even more as sometimes the explicit wait wasn't enough as it would find the element and continue on before something else needed to happen.  This was an issue with overlays and toast messages mainly.

Soooo, I implemented a "Speed Trackbar" into the GUI of the test fixture and set the intervals from 0 to 2.5 seconds, which controls, yes, here it goes, a Thread.Sleep.  This allows me to control the speed of which all commands get executed.  Even though the explicit wait is still there.