# Set the speed of simulation for Selenium on Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

I'm using Selenium to test my web application using c#.
But the simulation speed is too fast and I want to slow it down.
Is there any solution to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we set the speed of the webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20675630/can-we-set-the-speed-of-the-webdriver)

Comment: the new version havent the property ImplicitlyWait.

Comment: The point is, why do you need it? you can still Thread.Sleep the thread if you want to, but if they removed the functionality, it was probably to make a statement, that this is a bad practice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slowing down Selenium in Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49209720/slowing-down-selenium-in-node)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is it because the test fails (e.g. to find elements that are not rendered fast enough after a click)? is it because you want to see in your own eyes what the test does? or you want to record a video of the test to be able to investigate failures? Or something else? For each of these questions I have a different answer for you.

Comment: because the test fails, i solve it by a delay

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fiddler core API](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore) integration

```
  if (m_SimulateModem) 
  {
      // Delay sends by 300ms per KB uploaded.
      oSession["request-trickle-delay"] = "300"; 
      // Delay receives by 150ms per KB downloaded.
      oSession["response-trickle-delay"] = "150"; 
  }
```